# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, applet, drawimage

I have this problem with my applet. It only paints ONE row before it produces the error.

Here's my code: http://www.so.pastebin.com/RkG5YHVQ

Here's the error: http://www.so.pastebin.com/z1qWpFS6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change line `38` to:

```
int line = Integer.parseInt(src.next().trim());
```

This will trim off any whitespace from the number string that is causing the error in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `dan.txt` contains an extra newline before a zero.

Comment: Here is dan.txt

0,1,2,3,4,2,3,3,
0,1,2,3,4,2,3,3,
0,1,2,3,4,2,3,3,
0,1,2,3,4,2,3,3,
0,1,2,3,0,2,3,3,
0,1,2,3,4,2,3,3,
0,1,2,3,4,2,3,3,
0,1,2,3,4,2,3,3,

I don't think so. :\

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your scanner is not using whitespace as a delimiter, and `Integer.parseInt(src.next());` is choking on the first newline it finds.

You could try something like `src.useDelimiter("[,\\s]+")` to use any grouping of one or more whitespace and comma characters as delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you start to debug this problem :

Read through the stack trace bottom up and notice where your Java source files start to show up.  In your case:

```
Inventory.paint(Inventory.java:51)
```

Now you can start to debug this line using several different methods.  The preferred approach is to attach a debugger to a running instance of your program and see what happens at this line.  If you can't do that, simply add a try catch block to capture the exception around that line of code and print out the actual value vs the expected value.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For inpu
t string: "
0"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.
java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
Tile0   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)

        at Inventory.paint(Inventory.java:51)  <===== Your code shows up!
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:248)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:224)
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:306)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4706)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
Row: 1 successfully painted.
```